# php - string to key-value (associative) array type conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, key-value

I have data as a string, for example:

```
$a = '{"ip":"111.11.1.1","country":"abc","country_code":"xy","city":"xxx"}';
```

How to convert it into "key=>value" (associative) array like this :

```
   ip           => 111.11.1.1
   country      => abc
   country_code => xy
   city         => xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then cast to **array**:

```
$str = '{"ip":"111.11.1.1","country":"abc","country_code":"xy","city":"xxx"}';
$arr = (array)json_decode($str);
```

Or use the `assoc` flag in json_decode as:

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
```

Will result in:

```
array(4) {
  'ip' =>
  string(10) "111.11.1.1"
  'country' =>
  string(3) "abc"
  'country_code' =>
  string(2) "xy"
  'city' =>
  string(3) "xxx"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is what I am looking for ...

Comment: @KiranKumar You welcome - if my post help you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Yes, I've Accepted ...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `json_decode()` like this

```
$json = '{"ip":"111.11.1.1","country":"abc","country_code":"xy","city":"xxx"}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arr);
```

this will give you the desired result. This will print:

```
Array ( [ip] => 111.11.1.1 [country] => abc [country_code] => xy [city] => xxx )
```